# How to resize the component depending on the size of its sibling in React?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, reactjs

I have two sibling components, and the one on the left is changing the height. Its sibling on the right should change its height to the same size.

How do I accomplish something this in React?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would set it up:

1. Have a store, and in that store, have a value `thingyHeight` and set it to some default.
2. In a component that will change its height, have an event handler (perhaps on `mouseup` or something) that updates the value of 'thingyHeight` in the store.
3. Pass the value of `thingyHeight` to your right component.

This is what people are referring to when they talk about 'declarative' programming. You are *declaring* how your component should know its height (by the `thingyHeight` prop you pass it), you are not telling it *how* or *when* to change it's height (that's called *imperative*).

When the value changes in the store, React will re-render and set the new height if it needs to.